# WCF Service application with windows authentication and cross-platform?

Tags: wcf

Is it possible to have a WCF Service application (.NET 4.0) with Windows Authentication and cross-platform?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As recommended in the below MSDN link

[MSDN WCF Security](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731059.aspx)

make use of certificates.

I am currently using X509 Certificate

Answer (score 2):

No, I wouldn't recommend that. Kerberos, which is what windows authentication can use, should be interoperable in theory, but that's only theory. I have never seen a real implementation using this, it's almost impossible. You should use certificates, SAML or username and password.

Regards
Pablo.

Comment: for example, I may use basic authentication with https? is this correct?

Comment: Yes, basic auth over https works very well accross different platforms